# Finding the limits of integration for $\iint\limits_A \frac{1}{(1 + x^2 + y^2)^2} dxdy$ where A is one loop of lemniscate $(x^2 + y^2)^2 = x^2 - y^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Work so far: Switch to polar coordinates

$A \rightarrow r^2 = \cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta \rightarrow r^2 = \cos2\theta$

So $A$ is $r^2 = \cos 2 \theta$

And the integral becomes

$$\iint\limits_A \frac{r}{(1 + r^2)}drd\theta$$

Now I want to find the limits of integration without actually graphing the curve.

So

$$2rdr = -2\sin(2\theta)$$

$$\frac{dr}{d\theta} = \frac{-\sin(2\theta)}{r}$$

Critical points for $\theta$ come out to be $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Now I know how to solve the integral using u substitution but I'm not sure about the limits.

Comment: Why do you need the critical points? Look for the range of $\theta$ where the inequality $\cos2\theta\ge0$ holds.

Comment: @user $\frac{\pi}{4} \rightarrow 0$ seems right but where does $\cos 2\theta \geq 0$ come from?

Comment: The equation $r^2=\cos2\theta$ has real solutions for $r$ if and only if $\cos2\theta\ge0$.

Comment: Ah so to get every possible value, $\theta$ should go from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $0$. So does that mean $r$ should go from $0$ to its maximum possible bound? How should I go about finding that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates the curve is determined by 
$$r^2=\cos2\theta,
$$
which has real solutions for $r $ if and only if:
$$
\cos2\theta\ge0 \implies -\frac\pi4\le\theta\le\frac\pi4\text { or }\frac{3\pi}4\le\theta\le\frac{5\pi}4.$$

As the problem asks to find the area of a single loop it suffices to consider only the first interval. We have:

$$\iint\limits_A \frac{r}{(1 + r^2)^2}drd\theta=
\int\limits_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi4}d\theta
\int\limits_0^\sqrt {\cos2\theta}\frac{rdr}{(1 + r^2)^2}.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, definitely! Thank you.

Comment: One question if you don't mind, why are the limits of $r$ are from $0 \rightarrow \sqrt{\cos 2 \theta}$?

Comment: You are welcome. The only solutions of the equation $r^2=\cos2\theta$ are $r=\pm\sqrt{\cos2\theta}$. The negative square root belongs to the other loop of the curve ($\frac{3\pi}4\le\theta\le\frac{5\pi}4$).